# C# Black rectangle while focus by pressing tabulator key

Tags: c#, user-controls, runtime, paint

I need some help with creating a user control in my own design. I've created a user control and it's nearly finished. It needs only a bit polish...

My problem: 
If I focus my user control by pressing the tab key (at run time, not design time), there is a annoying rectangle (black) painted on it.

This is my current 'solution': 
Simply overpaint the rectangle with the right brush.

```
private void ButtonOnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (Image != null | BackgroundImage != null)
        return;

    var penColor = Color.Transparent;

    if (!_mouseCurrentMoveOver)
        penColor = BackgroundColor;
    else if (_mouseCurrentMoveOver)
        penColor = MouseOverBackColor;

    if (_mouseCurrentDown)
        penColor = MouseDownBackColor;

    if (penColor == Color.Transparent)
        return;

    using (var p = new Pen(penColor))
    {
        var startPoint = new Point(5, 5);
        var sizeRectangle = new Size(
            _button.Width - startPoint.X * 2 - 1, 
            _button.Height - startPoint.Y * 2 - 1);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, sizeRectangle.Width, sizeRectangle.Height);
    }
}
```

The reason why this not works is, if I set a *BackgroundImage* - it will be over painted by the *OnPaint* event.

**So the question is: How do I disable this focus rectangle?**

Comment: You may want to look inti  [this  on showfocuscues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.showfocuscues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you try this: `protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I've tried this, but nothing changes... ?

Answer (score 0):

In the user control's constructor you can call

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
```

This will disable the ability to select controls in the usercontrol by e.g. tabbing. If that is a function you want to keep, then this solution does not work for you.

Comment: Well, I think he want to keep the ability to have focues and juast get rid of the cues..

Comment: @TaW This might be true, or not. Given that you still get the MouseOver effects and the like, this might work for him. It would be hard to use the Tab selection without any marking anyways.

Comment: @Jens: The ability to select by tabbing should be available... your suggestion is very interesting - thanks for this! -  but it won't work for this :)